# azure function or web service with Internal IP address

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I need to create an azure function or web service but I need to add an internal IP address

Is this possible?

Which is the minimum App service Plan required for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need an internal IP Address I believe the only option is by using App Service Environment.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro

However, if you just need to block public access, you can achieve this by using Service Endpoints:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions